# How do I force ngx-translate to work offline?

Tags: ngx-translate

Working on a large existing Angular project, I discovered that modifying the JSON files containing translations had no effect on the project. I infer that it is getting them from a server. Generally speaking, how do I disable this?

The project involves Typescript and Ionic, and I'm using a pipe to translate within the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

What happened in my case was, In case of offline/server down state, default language to translation service was not set, as soon as I set it to 'en_us' default, even in offline case translation is working :)

Something like

```
if(!navigator.isOnline) {
     this.translate.setDefaultLang('en_us');
}
```

this is all I did. Hope it helps someone. I did this in my Ionic 5 project.

Comment: That makes sense! Unfortunately I will never be able to test this myself as I have no access to the project anymore, but thank you!

Comment: @Lenoxus no issues